# Log4J2 Rolling File Appender, is modulate required in this scenario's triggering policy?

Tags: java, log4j

Due to the vulnerabilities in Log4J framework, I have had to upgrade from 1.x to 2.17.1, which required rewriting the configuration used.

I have an application that is very dependent on a daily log file which is rolled over at midnight (or within 10 seconds of it, either before or after). It will log a counter every 10 seconds of previously ingested records (even if no data is being consumed), so I know that the appender should work as expected since it will always be logging a value every 10 seconds.

The smallest date pattern is the day value (ie; LogFile.log.2022-02-22) and my understanding is that this means that modulate will allow this to rollover once that smallest pattern has changed. Is this the case?

I currently do not have modulate set to true, and in my testing it seems to be working as expected, but I've only been able to do a little bit of testing since it requires the day to change, and I can't change the system time of my development environment for many reasons.

In this case, should I be using modulate?

I have read this post: [What does modulate = 'true' signify in Log4j TimeBased Triggering Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62517366/what-does-modulate-true-signify-in-log4j-timebased-triggering-policy)

but I'm still a little confused in my testing.

Here is the triggering policy I have as of testing:

```
<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
```

and here is the filePattern:

```
filePattern="${sys:logLocation}/${sys:job}-${sys:hostname}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}"
```

Comment: I believe there is a mistake in [Ralph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62539515/11748454): with your pattern rollover will always occur at midnight, `modulate` only decides whether the day of the year it occurs must be divisible by `interval` or not. In your case it does not matter.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was wondering. Since the smallest time unit is days, there isn't really a mid point to change according to startup time. It's either the next day or not, if I had logs with a file pattern that was hours or minutes I'd understand the usefulness. Thanks for response.

Comment: Wanted to confirm. Moved my upgrade to an active production environment and working as anticipated. Modulate is not required for day to day changes, as long as logs occur around the time that the rollover should occur. Rolling file appenders only trigger if there are active logs occurring.